# Disable skins command?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there a way to disable skins on CS:GO so i can see only the default skin? I was wondering if skins decrease FPS(i barely get 50-60 FPS).

Comment: Skins are simple textures (ie. images). Except for a little memory usage,  there is nothing that reduces FPS in CS:GO. Also: what are you using to play CS:GO? Even 5-7 year old PCs get way more than 60 FPS.

Comment: i have a Samsung 530U

Comment: The issue is: Ultrabooks like yours are not meant to play games with. The integrated graphics are not capable of even simple 3D rendering. It's not a (V)RAM issue and removing some textures won't help. Try lowering the details especially AA and shadows to improve performance; that's all you can do.

Comment: I already lowered everything :(

Comment: By writing +mat_queue_mode 2 in the csgo launch option you will bost the fps slightly

Answer (score 2):

No and no. Easiest way to increase FPS would be to lower your resolution. If you're playing in 1080p, try reducing to 720p. It puts less of a load on your GFX card/CPU.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

tested

Setting CS: GO
To begin, open the STEAM library, then select "Properties" - "Startup Parameters"
and insert the command data to a string:

- Cl_showfps 1 - Shows FPS game
  -novid - Removes the Negro at the beginning of the game
  -threads 6 - ???
  -high - Sets CS high priority
  -freq 60 - Frequency monitor upgrade
  -tickrate 128 - Tikreyt
  -dxlevel 81 - Version DX
  -noaafonts - Removes the font smoothing in
  -heapsize - Insert the number of your card
  512MB = 393216
  1GB = 786432
  1,5GB = 1179648
  2GB = 1572864
  4 GB = 3145728

Next, go to the game, and then in the graphics settings, and change settings such as:
Global Shadow Quality - Very Low

Model / Texture Detail - Low

Effect Detail - Low

Shader Detail - Low

Multicore Rendering - Enabled

Multisampling Anti-Aliasing Mode - 8x MSAA (Optional)

Texture Filtering Mode - Bilinear

FXAA Anti-Aliasing - Disabled

Wait for Vertical Sync - Disabled

Motion Blur - Disabled

Bonus++ ))
Control Panel - Power Options - Setting the Sleep - Change advanced power settings - PCI Express - Power management link state - Value: Off.

Next, open the NVIDIA Control Panel, and in the list of "3D Settings", select "Manage 3D settings", select the Counter-strike: Global Offensive and enter these settings:
The anisotropic filtering: OFF
Vertical sync: Off
ambient light Shading: OFF
The maximum number of pre-trained staff: 4
Streaming Optimization: ON (If more than one processor)
Upravlyaeniya Mode Power: Preferred maximum performance mode
Anti-aliasing - Gamma correction: OFF
Smoothing - Transparency: Off
Triple Buffering: OFF
Texture filtering - optimizing the anisotropic sample: OFF
Texture filtering - Quality: High performance
Texture filtering - negative deviation UD: Binding
Texture filtering - Trilinear optimization: Off

Comment: Sorry, but the asked to disable skins, not a general optimization guide.